# how to stop .cshrc file from auto loading?

Tags: shell, csh

When we open a new  konsole or xterm .cshrc file automatically get sourced.
But I dont wnat it to get sourced.
So how can I make a .cshrc not get sourced on opening up a new shell or konsole.

It should only be sourced if following command is used

```
source.cshrc
```

Comment: Do you want something else to run instead or not have it run?

Comment: I want .cshrc to be there but it should not run

Comment: Okay then, see what chepner wrote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of `.cshrc` is to run on shell startup. If you want a file that only runs when explicitly sourced, name it something else.